# Python - Writing For Loop as file as generator not str/dict

Tags: python

I'm a beginner developer and I'm trying to write the following variable in a for loop to a file, but it's trying to write as a str when it's a generator.  I also receive unsupported operand type when trying with my second method.

```
divdir = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div DSS Directors, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'])
for b in divdir:
    with open ('test2.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write (b)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
divdir = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div DSS Directors, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'])
my_file=open("test2.txt","w")
for b in divdir:
    my_file.write(b.get('divdir')+'\n')
my_file.close()
```

The error it gives is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Use `dict[foo]` instead of `dict.get(foo)`. This will fail if the element isn't contained in the dict, which seems to be the case here. `dict.get(foo)` will silently return `None` if `foo` isn't contained, and your code fails somewhere later, in your case at the `+` operation.

Comment: In your first code block, to reduce overhead of open and closing the same file multiple times, you should nest the `for` loop under the `with` statement. In your second block `b` is a key of `divdir` so to access the value, you want to `divdir[b]` to access it.

Comment: using dict[b] gives me TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable.  Same with using divdir[b].  However, it states generator object is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comments altogether, you should be good with the following adjusted statement.

This performs a single write to the file which prepares all your output beforehand (including setting `generator=False`) and writing it all at once by joining all the values:

```
divdir = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div DSS Directors, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'], generator=False)
directors = map(str, divdir)         #Stringify each director from generator
directors_str = '\n'.join(directors) #Join the list of directors with a newline
with open('test2.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(directors_str)        #Write to file
```

Comment: When I try the single write to the file.  It gives me the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ldapsearch.py", line 11, in <module>
    file.write('\n'.join(national.values()))
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Well then `national` must be a generator, and not a dict.

Comment: @user1470034 Looking at the [docs](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/standard.html), can you add the `generator=False` parameter to `paged_search()`?

Comment: I tried that and get list object has no attribute values.

Comment: You try without it? My apologies, I didn't update the code from when it was assumed to be a `dict` type.

Comment: Trying without it gives generator object has no attribute values.

Comment: When I try the updated code it gives TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

Comment: This would go a lot smoother had we known the data structure beforehand. When you use stringify the value with `str()` from another answer, which key are you looking to get? You should be able to plop in your key name in my updated answer.

Comment: I understand, honestly I didn't know there was a generator data structure.  I'm new to this.  I was just trying to get your single write to the file that prepped the output before hand.  Originally I thought it was a dict.  Doctors answer writes the output to the file when casting as a str.   I'm not looking for a specific key, just the entire output of each member in the distribution list.

Comment: Ok, updated again to reflect your current scenario. And broke apart the code to follow easily.

Comment: Thank you Sunny, i gave you credit for the answer since yours is the most elegant.  Could you explain what stringify is?

Comment: Thanks. Stringify is to transform the object into a string representation. A type of serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting the dictionary to a String with using `str()`. Should look something like:

```
for b in divdir:
    with open ('test2.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write (str(b))
```

For that `TypeError`, when you call `b.get('divdir')` the result is `None`.
You may want to double check you are using the correct key name or you can provide a default value to use if the dictionary does not contain that key.

`x = b.get('divdir', 'some default value')`

If the key `divdir` does not exist in `b` then the value of `x` will be "some default value".

Comment: OP had it backwards. The `for` loop gets all the keys from `divdir` and temporarily stores them one at a time in `b`. So they are guaranteed to exist. [`b` is not a dict](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/tutorial_searches.html#simple-paged-search).

Comment: Casting the dictionary as a string worked for me.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json` library to write your `dict` object to a file.  Try this:

```
import json

# divdir = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div DSS Directors, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'])
divdir={'raw_dn': b'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'dn': 'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'raw_attributes': {'member': [b'CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']}, 'attributes': {'member': ['CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']}, 'type': 'searchResEntry'}

with open('test2.txt', 'w') as file:   
  file.write(json.dumps(divdir))
```

Comment: I tried json, but it gives me the following error:  TypeError: Object of type 'generator' is not JSON serializable